# How can i make a lock screen in iPhone?

Tags: ios

I want to make a lock screen in iPhone which has just one button on it, which is titled as unlock, after tapping that button a barcode scanner opens up, which scans the barcode, unlocks the phone. The lock screen should remain even on the clicking or double clicking the home button.

Can i do this in an iPhone? Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't.
The suggestion: read the [Human Interface Guidlines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: can you give any alternate idea in order to implement this??